# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH but it's already there

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I want to send a message to [this website](https://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id=13829371) with Python.

It is to say to do the following but with python :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

That's why I tried the following script with Selenium:

```
api_location = 'http://iphoneapp.spareroom.co.uk'
api_search_endpoint = 'flatshares'
api_details_endpoint = 'flatshares'

location = 'http://www.spareroom.co.uk'
details_endpoint = 'flatshare/flatshare_detail.pl?flatshare_id='
def contact_room(self, room_id):
    url = '{location}/{endpoint}/{id}?format=json'.format(location=self.api_location, endpoint=self.api_details_endpoint, id=room_id)
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    # Go to your page url
    driver.get(url)
    # Get button you are going to click by its id ( also you could use find_element_by_css_selector to get element by css selector)
    button_element = driver.find_element_by_id('button id')
    button_element.click()
```

But it returns:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\roomfinder>python test_message.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_message.py", line 21, in <module>
    contact_room(13829371)
  File "test_message.py", line 14, in contact_room
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

While I already added it in the PATH:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<sub>I am javascript learner. If you have tips and time to show how to answer the question as well in Javascript I am always happy to learn :)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chromedriver needs to be in the path of your python script or you need to add it to your driver:

```
driver_path = 'Path\to\your\Driver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path)
```

Why are you using `webdriver.Firefox()` if you talk about `Chrome`?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's `webdriver.Chrome()` indeed. Should it be `driver_path = C:\Program Files` for instance if my driver is there ? Yet I get `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Program Files' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: No it should be ```driver_path = C:\Program Files\chromedriver``` or ```driver_path = C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe```.